# How can people read S4 data?

Tags: online-storage

There is a service called [**Super Simple Storage Service**](http://supersimplestorageservice.com) (or **S4**)

They say:

> S4's state-of-the-art write-only interface removes the headaches commonly associated with reading data.

OK, so how can I *read* and/or *download* the data?

**UPDATE**: I always think this service is real until I click the Paypal link and I know this is a *troll*. Sorry for this stupid question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read or download, that is what lets S4 offer such speedy and cheap services!

By not allowing reads, S4 is faster and more secure while being more simple for customers to use.

Comment: Isn't `/dev/null` cheaper in terms of bandwidth use?

Comment: I understand that, but a storage service without reading is useless
@DeerHunter Yeah, 0$ to use and you have unlimited storage capacity!

Comment: @DeerHunter - but that only works locally, this provides REST, SOAP & YouTube comments access

Comment: @HồTuấnKiệt check out their Paypal links

Comment: Now I know this is a joke and I am a idiot :(